# Metro App mailto protocol doesn't accept HTML?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, mailto

I am trying to make a metro app which involves the user sending out an invitation email to friends. To do this, I am using the mailto:// protocol. However, if I try to include HTML tags in the body section, the Mail app reads them literally and displays raw HTML to the user. Is there any way to get around this?

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Comment: Have you considered the share charm, instead of using mailto?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the share charm is for receiving data and responding to data requests. I don't see how it could accomplish an email task.

Comment: The Windows Mail app is a share target; it means that the user can share to it as a target for whatever content is being viewed in some other app. Find any aweb page you want to share, and invoke the share charm from there; mail will be listed and allow lost of customization of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently hunting for an answer to a similar problem, only in my case I also want to embed an image in the body of the email. I have not dug into the code much, but it seems like the Mail app does not handle all the protocols required to attach additional files to the html body. For the simple case though - you should be able to share your html being the share source and invoking the share charm. You are not limiting the user from using other applications as share targets for your html and you probably can't define the subject or recipients, but it's the best I could find.

There is a sample you can check here: "[Sharing content source app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84)".

Comment: No better solution probably exists for now.